# Filling up a field inside a struct

Tags: c

I am trying to fill up a field inside a struct but am a little confused as how to do so:
following is the struct:

```
struct ofp_packet_out {
    struct ofp_header header;
    uint32_t buffer_id;           /* ID assigned by datapath (-1 if none). */
    uint16_t in_port;             /* Packet's input port (OFPP_NONE if none). */
    uint16_t actions_len;         /* Size of action array in bytes. */
    struct ofp_action_header actions[0]; /* Actions. */
     uint8_t data[0];         /* Packet data.  The length is inferred
                                     from the length field in the header.
                                     (Only meaningful if buffer_id == -1.) */
};
OFP_ASSERT(sizeof(struct ofp_packet_out) == 16);
```

The field I am trying to fill up is uint8_t data[0]. It will be a char array, assuming
that we have a buffer

```
char * buf[150]={some data};
```

the field   struct ofp_action_header actions[0];  is an action array that can be used to append multiple actions, an example of which is

```
typedef struct ofp_action_output ofp_action_output;
ofp_action_output  action = *((ofp_action_output*)ofm.actions);
        memset(&action, 0, sizeof(ofp_action_output));
        action.type = htons(OFPAT_OUTPUT);
        action.len = htons(sizeof(ofp_action_output));
        action.port = htons(OFPP_FLOOD);
        action.max_len = htons(0);
```

where ofm is `struct some_struct ofm;` which has the fields actions. 
What I am struggling is to how to do the same thing with the field  `uint8_t data[0];`
As I mentioned I have the required data extracted in an array and I need to put that data
into the struct field  `uint8_t data[0];`so that the data I received from the switch can be sent back to it.

how do I append it to the required field? All help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a C answer or a C++ answer? Don't tag both languages.

Comment: Leaving aside the wisdom and portability of zero-length arrays, you can't have more than one of them; it only makes sense for the last element in the struct to be a zero-length array.

Comment: I would prefer a C answer. the fact is that the struct is actually an implementation of OPENFLOW specification built into a network switch. When the switch cant buffer the packet data, it sends it to our program (the whole data.), that data I stored in a char array like I mentioned, now I need to append that data to the field and as you can see in the comments we can set the size of supposedly zero size data array to whatever we want by specifying the size in the header length field.

Comment: You might also want to add `attribute((packed))` to the declaration of the struct in order to prevent gcc from inserting extra padding bytes for optimal member alignment. That is, of course, valid only if you'd want to pass the pointer to this structure directly to a function like read() or write().

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
ofp_packet_out myobj;
memcpy(myobj.data, buf, 150);
```

Not terribly safe, but you appear to have a C cant.

That won't append it, but rather overwrite it. To append to a field you would have to show me that field as you have currently commented it out. You would also want the position where you should append to within the destination.

Above all both arrays/buffers must have specified capacity, ie 150 bytes.

Forgive me, are you looking to copy into that struct without having field handle for the destination address? That would require a lot more work as it depends on your compiler set up how much space is used for the preceding fields. Summing `sizeof(objname.fieldname)` would not work due to internal padding and word alignment.

Comment: that right there is the problem, I am familiar with the memcpy process but we cant just access the field that is inside a struct can we ? dont we have to point to it first like ofp_packet_out.data  or something ?

Comment: I don't understand, aren't you missing some parameters to the equation you present? To be honest I don't understand why you have a zero length array `struct ofp_action_header actions[0];` and no field handle for the destination you are alluding to.

Comment: @Abdullah, yes, you can just access the field that is inside the struct. I don't know the current rules on having 2 zero length arrays, it seems unworkable. If you know the field name, as you claim to, you can access it.